# IIS 7 - bit rate throttling - site target throughput

Tags: iis, iis-7, server, bandwidth, throttling

Not a big IIS user, but I have a lot of traffic on my site at certain times. The traffic is related to heavy downloads so I was looking at the bit rate throttling.

What I am not sure about is what to set the site target throughput to. Should this be the maximum upload speed of the server?

The maximum upload speed of the server's internet is roughly 6-7mbps so should i use that as the target throughput, or am I looking at this wrong?

Comment: Is your content fairly static? CloudFlare does an awesome job of this free with almost no configuration.

Comment: ill have a look. Our hosting provider is fast and awesome, its more that we have files users get for our software at particular points in the day so there are just bit loads on the server. The bit rate solution is basically a temporary fix, until i build a system for our software to be distributed among other servers to take the load.